# Reading SMTP mail in one line

Tags: c++, unix, smtp

I'm trying to get a single line of UNIX to read and then delete an email (because I want to call the one line from a C++ function).

If I do this:

```
/bin/echo -ne "USER test@mail.co.uk\nPASS fred\nLIST\nRETR 1\nQUIT" | /usr/bin/nc -i 1 mail.site 110
```

...it works fine, returning the mail contents.

My problem is the delete bit - I have to delete the mail after reading it but, for some reason, the command below is not working:

```
/bin/echo -ne "USER test@mail.co.uk\nPASS fred\nLIST\nDELE 1\nQUIT" | /usr/bin/nc -i 1 mail.site 110
```

Output is:

```
+OK Dovecot ready.
+OK
+OK Logged in.
+OK 2 messages:
1 3913
2 3925
.
+OK Marked to be deleted.
```

...but if I repeat the LIST command, both mails still appear.

The DELE command works fine if I telnet in and do it interactively but not from the one line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the correct end-of-line sequence is CRLF (`"\r\n"`).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just the way? You ask the question and then 2 minutes later, you find the answer...

I just needed an extra '\n' after the QUIT command. Triggers mail to actually do the delete. Doh!